# Angular does not run on my created proxy and put its default localhost before my api

Tags: angular

I created a proxy in a created file as the following:

```
{
"/api/*": {
  "target": "https://localhost:44361",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

}

in my package.json i edited like this:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
```

after i restart the project it says its built succefully in the new proxy but in my project when i run :

```
    getPosts(x){  

   // return  this.http.post(this.url,{params:{username:x}});
    return this.http.post('/api/Auth/token/', "morteza")
  .pipe(map(user => {
  // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
  if (user ) {
  // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
  localStorage.setItem('TokenInfo', JSON.stringify(user));
  }

   return user;
  }));
```

it does not apply my url on the created proxy and runs on Angular default localhost:4200

Comment: this looks correct. the request in the network tab will still show the localhost:4200 url but it will be proxied to the targeturl you set in your config. Do you get an error from the api? And is your api mapped to localhost:44361/api/Auth/token/  or localhost:44361/Auth/token/ ?

Comment: @FrankAdrian i did this to get rid of the blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin,but now it runs on localhost:4200\/api/Auth/token/ and says error 500

Comment: thats good, it means the error is coming from the server, do you have the api path defined on your api? Maybe try it with `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }` added to your config.

Comment: @FrankAdrian where should i write that?

Comment: if that does not help, look at the console of your server and angular app, it should give you more infos on the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{
"/api/*": {
  "target": "https://localhost:44361",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }
}
```

Comment: i get zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:4200/api/Auth/token/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: im getting the same thing 404 not found ,i dont get error 500

Comment: ahh, you have https in the target url, should it be http only?

Comment: but my back end APi (.NetCore)when i run its on https

Comment: could this be a "certificate" issue?
Check this documentation (**secure** option)
https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options